# Searching github branches by date range

Tags: git, github

I have a repo with ~100 branches and I'm trying to find a code snipped in one of the branches that I need to reimplement.  Is there a way in Github to search for branches that were created within a specified date range?  Otherwise it's sifting through 100 branches for a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I use an alias for this i found a long time ago, the command looks like this:

```
!git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/heads/ --format='%(color:yellow)%(refname:short)|%(color:bold green)%(committerdate:relative)|%(color:blue)%(subject)|%(color:magenta)%(authorname)%(color:reset)' | column -ts'|'
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you click on commits at the top of the window then you can see the edit history of the entire repo.